# How to decrease footer size?

Tags: header-footer, page, footer

I want to reduce footer size to the maximum extent possible and for that I am using the following command:

```
\usepackage[top=1em, bottom=1em, left=0.2in, right=0.2in]{geometry}
```

But some how, the space is not getting reduced at all.As you can see, the text is getting shifted to the next page. Can someone help me in reducing the footer size ?

Here is an image of my document:

[image: Sample text]

EDIT:

Here are the commands I have used to make it work :

```
\usepackage[top=0pt ,foot=0pt, bottom=0.01in, left=0.2in, right=0.2in{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{Header}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
```

The `showframe` output looks like this:

[image: showframe output]

Comment: You can use the `showframe` option in `geometry` to see the page area. Also, there is the `foot` space you can control.

Comment: @Sigur : I am getting  "Option clash for package xcolor." error when I use showframe

Comment: How are you using it? It should be inside the brackets, after the margins, for example.

Comment: @Sigur I disabled xcolor. Now I am able to see the page area and it shows a large footer space as expected. I want to reduce it. How to control the foot space ?

Comment: Like you did for `top`, for example, you can do `foot=0em` (if not, please, try `footer` I'm not sure). But observe that this will overprint any footer content. Maybe what you want is to use `includefoot`. Search for `geometry` here and there are many examples.

Comment: I tried foot=0em but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Includefoot also doesn't make any difference. Although, my header height is changing and I am able to reduce it but not the footer.

Comment: So, please, edit your post and show us a minimal code so we could reproduce your problem. Maybe your contents is to big to fit in the same page. It is not a footer related problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78979/discussion-between-shreyas-and-sigur).

Comment: your image looks like a table, does the next row of the table fit on the page (it looks like it may not but you have not given anything like enough information to be able to offer any help)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, it is a table . And it does fit on the page.

Comment: yes i saw your overleaf link in the associated chat room

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `\textheight=10in` so cutting off the page at 10in, over-riding the page settings from `geometry` simply delete that line.  (This was not shown in the question, but in a link to overleaf in the comments)